# SQL Subquery: Show Customer_IDs that have purchased two items

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

EDIT:

Thanks all. It should have been CustomerID, not productID, linking these two tables. Even with that, the query didn't return any customer IDs due to what Squirrel said; it was a bad query. I have found better success using the following syntax:

```
SELECT distinct(c.customerID)
FROM sales.customer c inner join sales.SalesOrderHeader h
on c.CustomerID = h.CustomerID
inner join sales.SalesOrderDetail l on h.SalesOrderID = l.SalesOrderID
WHERE l.ProductID IN (710, 715)
GROUP BY c.customerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.ProductID) = 2
```

I'm trying to return `CustomerID`s that have purchased two items with specific `ProductID`s (710 and 715) -- but have NOT purchased 716 -- from the `ProductID` column of a second table. I'm trying to perform this as a subquery, but I get an error

> SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'ProductID'

This is my block of code:

```
SELECT 
    sc.customerID
FROM
    sales.customer sc
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                  FROM sales.SalesOrderDetail sod 
                  WHERE sod.ProductID = 710)
    AND ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                      FROM sales.SalesOrderDetail sod 
                      WHERE sod.ProductID = 715)
    AND ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                      FROM sales.SalesOrderDetail sod 
                      WHERE sod.ProductID != 716)
```

Any help fixing the syntactical error would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can we see the schema of tables sales.customer and sales.SalesOrderDetail?

Comment: Try something like this:select sc.customerID
from sales.customer sc
WHERE ProductID IN 
(Select ProductID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID IN (710, 715))
AND ProductID NOT IN 
(Select ProductID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID = 716)

Comment: are you sure the `ProductID` column is in `SalesOrderDetail` table ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah, i beleive ProductID is in SalesOrderDetail but i dont think ProductID  should be in customer table. I beleive customerID should be the link between the two tables if the model is done right

Comment: Your first 2 `WHERE` condition does not make sense. Effectively you are saying `WHERE ProductID IN (710) AND ProductID  IN (715)` and the result is `false` there will not be a `ProductID` that can satisfy these 2 condition. You might want to take a look at `EXISTS()`

Comment: @zip - Thank you for the catch. You are correct that product ID is NOT in the customer table. Customer ID is the linking column. However, it does not return any results. I believe Squirrel was correct -- I have a bad query. I tried a different method and believe I achieved the desired result.

Comment: I have added a query as an answer, did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok on the question, but in the future, it is good to provide some samples of data, columns to get the point across.  You do not show how any a sales order joins to the sales order detail.  That being said, I will provide an EDUCATED guess at what you have.

I would do a query ONCE and get a count per product qualified... then apply HAVING.  Its possible for a person to have multiple orders and each product COULD be on a different order  (unless all you care about is all on the SAME order which would be slightly different).

```
select
      SO.CustomerID
      -- at THIS point, I only care did the person have any of the products
      max( case when SOD.ProductID = 710 then 1 else 0 end ) as HasProduct1,
      max( case when SOD.ProductID = 715 then 1 else 0 end ) as HasProduct2,
      max( case when SOD.ProductID = 716 then 1 else 0 end ) as HasProduct3
   from
      Sales.SalesOrder SO
         JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
            on SO.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
   group by
      SO.CustomerID
   having 
       -- NOW, we can apply the product 1 & 2 purchased, but NOT product 3
          max( case when SOD.ProductID = 710 then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND max( case when SOD.ProductID = 715 then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
      AND max( case when SOD.ProductID = 716 then 1 else 0 end ) = 0
```

If you remove the HAVING clause, you would be able to see ALL customers and if they had any combination, such as only product 1 and 3, only 2, or any combination including customers who ordered NONE of the products in question.

Comment: Interesting approach. I like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select sc.customerID from sales.customer sc 
WHERE 
ProductID IN (Select ProductID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID IN (710, 715)) 
AND 
ProductID NOT IN (Select ProductID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID = 716)
```

Run the subselect statements individually first to get the syntax right for that part, for your SQL engine.  For example, run this SQL query first:

```
Select ProductID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID IN (710, 715)
```

And when you have valid syntax and valid results THEN you can use this select as a sub-select statement.
Same for the "NOT IN" subselect.  Run it and get valid results THEN include it in the parentheses as your subselect.

Comment: I'll try this as an alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

THis is my take on this:
 i beleive ProductID is in SalesOrderDetail but i dont think ProductID should be in customer table. I beleive customerID should be the link between the two tables if the model is done right

```
select sc.customerID
from sales.customer sc
WHERE customerID IN 
(Select customerID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID = 710)
AND customerID IN 
(Select customerID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID = 715)
AND customerID NOT IN 
(Select customerID from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod where sod.ProductID = 716)
```

Comment: No, this did not work. It did not return any customer IDs. I created now code, which I posted under my edit at the top. That one seems to do the trick! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, I see, you removed the constraint on ProductID 716.